# Is it possible to execute two action listener on pressing a single view?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

Here relativeLayoutThemeChange is relativeLayout view i.e,
RelativeLayout id = "+@relativeLayoutThemeChange" <_imageView <-TextView ->  RelativeLayout->

```
     binding.relativeLayoutThemeChange.setOnClickListener {
                    if(condition){
                    AppUtils.getNightMode(appCompatActivity)}
                  
                    else{
               //condition 
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap two listers in one like this:

```
binding.relativeLayoutThemeChange.setOnClickListener {
    listenerOne()
    listenerTwo()
}
```